# Do you need user's permission to fetch Facebook Pages and Twitter Feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter-oauth

I want to know that do we need user's permission to curate users Twitter Feed and Facebook Pages?

I want to fetch the feed from Twitter and Facebook and show it in my app in a customized design. One of my developers said that it is not possible without users permission.

I was wondering if Facebook Pages Feed are public then you don't need permission likewise for Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Please consult the available docs first before posting a question. All info for your question is available with 2mins of googling...

For **Facebook**, you can use *any* access token to access a Page's *publicly shared posts*, as outlined in the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#readperms

So

> **Permissions**
>
> - An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
> - A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
> - A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.
> - A page access token is required for /{page-id}/promotable_posts.

For **Twitter**, you can use the application-only authentication:

- https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

> Your app will be able to, for example:
>
> - Pull user timelines;
> - Access friends and followers of any account;
> - Access lists resources;
> - Search in tweets;
> - Retrieve any user information;